# Graph problem on cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Given a simple graph $G(V,E)$ with 2020 vertices such that $\deg(v)\geqslant 45$ for every vertex $v\in V(G)$. Show that one can find a $4$-cycle in $G$.

I've managed to prove the statement for $n^2$ vertices, all of them with degree $\geqslant n+1$ with a simple Pigeonhole argument counting the number nice edge-pairs (i.e. pairs of edges that share a vertex). One should arrive at $$\binom{n^2}{2}<n^2\cdot \binom{n+1}{2}$$ which is the desired contradiction. However, the argument fails for $2020$ and $\deg\geqslant 45$.

I also tried to apply the idea displayed [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.mit.edu/%7Efox/MAT307-lecture09-10.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjKq77hlbHyAhXDnVwKHX1oB7cQFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3Hp8LOqA2ZQHriccJoUlDS) (first page) which leads to the inequality
$$n(n-1)\geqslant \sum_{u\in V}\deg(u)\cdot (\deg(u)-1)\implies 2020\cdot 2019\geqslant 2020\cdot 45\cdot 44 $$ But this is true and leads, therefore, to no contradiction.

Any ideas/hints?

Comment: The inequality $n(n-1)\geqslant \sum_{u\in V}\deg(u)\cdot (\deg(u)-1)$ is tight. In fact, if we had instead $\deg\geqslant 46$, this would do the trick!

Comment: @LozanoC Ah yes. Then I understand the argument, and I believe it is essentially the same as the second argument (divide/multiply everything by $2$).

Comment: That's right! But I currently see no way to refine it...

Comment: That's a question from the currently running German competition 'Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik'. Maybe it should be closed till September?

Comment: The link is here https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/fileadmin/Mathe-Wettbewerbe/Bundeswettbewerb_Mathematik/Dokumente/Aufgaben_und_Loesungen_BWM/aufgaben_21_2.pdf

Comment: @Jochen I have flagged it for the moderators in case you hadn't yet.

Comment: @Jochen thanks for pointing that out. Pragmatically, I agree that it would be better to put the question on hold until the competition is over. But can we do so in a way that is transparent and fair to OP, who may have found the problem through a different source? I have flagged the problem for moderator attention to see what they think. (I didn't notice Misha's comment, which appeared as I was typing a message to the moderators. So now it has been flagged at least twice.)

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn I think it is clear to me that this question is dishonest, because it has been modified very slightly from the competition problem: 2021 has been changed to 2020.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I thought problems rejected from the IMO shortlist were under embargo to be used by national Olympiads for a year (and so could be used by different countries). But maybe I misremembered or misunderstood — I'm not too familiar with the contest world.